# How can I leverage host.docker.internal for simultaneous use in both Docker's internal networking and public internet networking?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Original question was wrriten on [docker github discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/discussions/47112).

### Goal

As described in my `docker-compose.yml` file below, I've defined three Docker containers: `catalog-service`, `edge-service`, and `polar-keycloak`. What I want is to be able to access `polar-keycloak` from my local machine's browser via `http://host.docker.internal:8080` (You could achieve this by creating an additional alias called `host.docker.internal` that points to `127.0.0.1` in the `/etc/hosts` file on your host machine.), while simultaneously having `catalog-service` and `edge-service` access `polar-keycloak` via the same link (`http://host.docker.internal:8080`) within the Docker container cluster. To accomplish this, I configured `host.docker.internal:host-gateway` when defining `catalog-service` and `edge-service` in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but have not been successful.

```
    version: "3.8"
    services:
      catalog-service:
        depends_on:
          - polar-keycloak
        image: "catalog-service"
        container_name: "catalog-service"
        ports:
          - 9001:9001
        environment:
          - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_ISSUER_URI=http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/PolarBookshop
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
      edge-service:
        depends_on:
          - polar-keycloak
        image: "edge-service"
        container_name: "edge-service"
        ports:
          - 9000:9000
        environment:
          - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_KEYCLOAK_ISSUER_URI=http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/PolarBookshop
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
      polar-keycloak:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0
        container_name: "polar-keycloak"
        command: start-dev --import-realm
        volumes:
          - ./keycloak:/opt/keycloak/data/import
        environment:
          - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=user
          - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
```

#### Environment

- `Docker Engine (Not desktop) version:  24.0.7`
- `OS distro:  Manjaro Linux`

### debugging

Therefore, I started to troubleshoot the issue myself. I first attempted to run the `docker network ls` command:

```
    ➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker network ls                                                                                                                   
    NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE                                                                                                                     
    826180b597ee   bridge    bridge    local                                                                                                                     
    40581c0c5d46   host      host      local                                                                                                                     
    25d6480ec121   none      null      local
```

Next, I ran the `docker network inspect bridge` command to view the network named `bridge`. The results are displayed as follows:

```
<details><summary>docker network inspect bridge</summary>
<pre><code>
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker network inspect bridge                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        "Name": "bridge",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "Id": "826180b597ee643fd010a8843947b650bca65a0a17322749c9f4b21171951079",                                                                                                                                                                                             
        "Created": "2024-01-18T05:14:35.101019514+08:00",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "Scope": "local",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "Driver": "bridge",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        "EnableIPv6": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        "IPAM": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            "Driver": "default",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            "Options": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            "Config": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "Internal": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "Attachable": false,                                       
        "Ingress": false,                                          
        "ConfigFrom": {                                            
            "Network": ""                                          
        },                                                         
        "ConfigOnly": false,                                       
        "Containers": {},                                          
        "Options": {                                               
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",                                                                        
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",                                                                            
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",                                                                  
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",                                                                  
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",                                                                               
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"                                                                                    
        },                                                         
        "Labels": {}                                               
    }                                                              
]
</code></pre>
</details>
```

Subsequently, I ran the `docker compose up -d polar-keycloak catalog-service edge-service` command to launch these three docker containers. Immediately afterwards, I executed the `docker network ls` command again, and noticed that there was an additional network named `docker_default` in the results compared to before. I then ran the `docker network inspect docker_default` command to examine this `docker_default` network, and the results were as follows:

```
<details><summary>docker network inspect docker_default</summary>
<pre><code>
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker network inspect docker_default                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        "Name": "docker_default",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        "Id": "a35c758493b5dc228af55c8cc2fcb951b428d6c221a50bc34cd7b70ead13ee83",                                                                                                                                                                                             
        "Created": "2024-01-19T05:16:55.152853662+08:00",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "Scope": "local",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "Driver": "bridge",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        "EnableIPv6": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        "IPAM": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            "Driver": "default",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            "Options": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            "Config": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    "Subnet": "172.26.0.0/16",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    "Gateway": "172.26.0.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "Internal": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "Attachable": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        "Ingress": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "ConfigFrom": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            "Network": ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "ConfigOnly": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        "Containers": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            "b5feb0dda5f1393514c9e98506a3b8b869fca8df408e258fd7cd8d17324a63ad": {                                                      
                "Name": "catalog-service",                                                                                             
                "EndpointID": "342adb279ef2801ed5d9bdf645e7c6670eb8d06f8506c4c4686874f6fec37182",                                      
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:0a",                                                                                     
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.10/16",                                                                                       
                "IPv6Address": ""                                  
            },
            "b11b2b888d73d6c2be3cc5b77fee19217e007429534f3472db6a6c6ddf5a7f13": {                                                      
                "Name": "edge-service",                              
                "EndpointID": "266a823c3051faa0a7d0466186d3c13f81eaf7dab393c4d8e007be5f181f629b",                                      
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:03",                                                                                     
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.3/16",                                                                                        
                "IPv6Address": ""                                  
            },
            "eff2813f26a3208495873e63e016507e729a451c9cf2b5b2c9317c89d02bc3cf": {                                                      
                "Name": "polar-keycloak",                                                                                              
                "EndpointID": "21dd8a3c081b9b2e79aef44db5fdd1f703ddb9db3449641698206aa4fd890c4e",                                      
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:02",                                                                                     
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.2/16",                                                                                        
                "IPv6Address": ""                                  
            }                                                      
        },                                                         
        "Options": {},                                             
        "Labels": {                                                
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",                                                                                   
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",                                                                                    
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.23.3"                                                                                     
        }                                                          
    }                                                              
] 
</code></pre>
</details>
```

Finally, when I executed the `docker exec -it catalog-service bash` command to enter the `catalog-service` container, I used `cat /etc/hosts` to view the value of `host.docker.internal`. **Surprisingly, its value was the `Gateway` of the `bridge` network (i.e., "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"), not the corresponding `Gateway` value of `docker_default`!**

```
<details><summary>cat /etc/hosts</summary>
<pre><code>
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker exec -it catalog-service bash                                                                                                                                
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$                                                                                                                                                                 
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$                                                                                                                                                                 
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$ cat /etc/hosts                                                                                                                                                  
127.0.0.1       localhost                                                                                                                                                                    
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback                                                                                                                                                 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet                                                                                                                                                                         
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix                                                                                                                                                                      
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes                                                                                                                                                                         
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters                                                                                                                                                                       
172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal                                                                                                                                                         
172.26.0.10     b5feb0dda5f1                                                                                                                                                                 
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$                                                                                                                                                                 
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$                                                                                                                                                                 
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$                                                                                                                                                                 
cnb@b5feb0dda5f1:/workspace$ exit                                                                                                                                                            
exit                                                                                                                                                                                         
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ 
</code></pre>
</details>
```

### Question

After explaining the above background information, how should I go about achieving my goal?

Comment: The browser running on the host system will never be able to resolve the `host.docker.internal` host name.  I'd try to avoid using it at all in the setup you describe, and accept that container-to-container networking is different from host-to-container networking.

Comment: In a real production environment, `polar-keycloak` （which might be deployed on a different remote host machine）will possess its own URL that's accessible from the public internet. However, for convenience, I'm intending to use `http://host.docker.internal:8080` on my host to represent that public URL.

Comment: You **cannot** use `host.docker.internal` on your host (unless you add it to your `/etc/hosts` file with the address of the container, but that's fragile and will break every time you start a new container so don't do that). The address `host.docker.internal` is *only* valid inside a container (and under Linux, only if you've explicitly enabled it).

Comment: I don't understand why it is still failing even after I added the '127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal' entry to the /etc/hosts file on my computer. I am able to successfully access http://localhost:8080 in my host computer's web browser, but when I try to access http://host.docker.internal:8080, it doesn't work. I'm curious about the underlying cause.

Comment: Can you access 127.0.0.1:8080?

Comment: @user920391 On my host, I can access 127.0.0.1:8080 successfully.

Comment: So the issue is that you cannot access 127.0.0.1 via alias created in /etc/hosts. I don't think it is related to docker

Comment: @user920391 Indeed, you're correct. I'm currently able to reach `host.docker.internal:8080` from my host's chrome browser! However, I'm still encountering issues and am uncertain if the `extra_hosts` configuration in my `docker-compose.yml` is functioning properly.